# Renaming default.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, default, title

How do I rename the default.aspx page title if it exists at the root of my site? Right now, it shows 'Home' in the Page Header

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/newsite/default.aspx
```

Usually, the pages exist in a library and you can go modify the properties of the page through the browser or SharePoint designer. This site is migrated from SharePoint 2007 and there is no  tag in the aspx markup. Where is 'Home' coming from ?

This tag, which is rendering 'Home', is being rendered as DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea

```
<span id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea">
```

yet, that is nowhere to be found in the default.aspx markup

Comment: Is publishing enabled on that site?

Comment: no publishing is not enabled

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the "Home" in default.aspx, we can modify the code below in the defualt.aspx page using SharePoint Designer.

```
<tr class="s4-die">
 <td class="ms-pagebreadcrumb">
   Dennis
 </td>
</tr>
```

We can also use JavaScript code to rename it.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
   $(".ms-sitemapdirectional").text("Dennis");
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: thx but I want to rename not hide it

Comment: I modify the reply as above. Or we can use JavaScript to rename it.

Comment: we must be using a different layout, I don't see either of those classes in my aspx

Comment: Check the CSS class using IE F12 or Chrome F12, then modify the code to make it works.

Comment: Did you achieve this requirement ?